# Read command cuts text

Tags: bash

I have a menu script that reads an input of several lines of text, sometimes 40+ short lines (each line is a name of a specific job). I need to read these lines from a Windows paste function and store in a file for future manipulation. What I have now works on some PCs and doesn't work on others and I cannot figure out why.

1. It cuts the input randomly when I paste large amount of text using SSH Tectia
2. It will accept/read and save all lines from the Windows paste command on some PCs using Putty and not on others

Am I using the read command properly?

```
#!/bin/bash

# This will clear the screen before displaying the menu.
clear

# Clear Jobs File
echo > jobs.txt

while :
do
    # If error exists, display it
    if [ "$ERR_MSG" != "" ]; then
            echo "Error: $ERR_MSG"
            echo ""
    fi

    # Write out the menu options...
    echo " Select an option:"
    echo ""
    echo " Option 1: Enter Job Name(s)"
    echo " Option 2: Display Job Name(s) in File"
    echo " Option 3: Job(s) Status"


    # Clear the error message
    ERR_MSG=""

    # Read the user input
    read SEL

    case $SEL in
            1) echo "Paste Job Name(s) and Press "!" Once Done"; read -de "!" jobnames; echo $jobnames > jobs.txt ;;
            2) tr ' ' '\n' < jobs.txt ;;
            3) sh jobstat.sh;;
            4) break ;;
            *) ERR_MSG="Please enter a valid option!" ;;
    esac

    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "Press Enter to Retun to Main Menu"
    read key

    clear

done
```

Comment: It would be great if you can create some minimal but reproducible version, that is an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: AND that doesn't flag any errors at https://shellcheck.net . ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Do any of these files have `\r\n` line endings?  It could be that the `\r` is making it *appear* that data is missing.  This is typical of files that have been created by some Windows applications.  Use a utility like `dos2unix` to replace the alien line endings.

Comment: I edited the post with the actual script if that's better

Comment: It would be, but you used tabs for your indentation.  Please, don't use tabs.  Corrected.

Comment: BTW, nothing to do with your issue, but `echo > jobs.txt` does not clear the file, it actually writes a newline into it.  To clear the file to zero bytes you can use `> jobs.txt`, i.e. drop the `echo`.

Comment: You should look at the `select` command.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with this:

```
echo "Paste Job Name(s) and Press "!" Once Done"; read -de "!" jobnames; echo $jobnames > jobs.txt
```

Running this line gives:

```
read: `!': not a valid identifier
```

This is because you use `read -de`.  The `-d` should be followed by a delimiter, which is `e`.  So the `!` then is expected to be a variable name (identifier).

The `-e` option is only used for *interactive* session, which this is not, so I have no idea why you would need it.  Drop the `e` or use `-ed`.

Second, using `"!"` is dangerous in bash because the `!` is a special character for event recall.  It won't normally be an issue in a script, but better to escape it and the quotes around it:

```
echo "Paste Job Name(s) and Press \"\!\" Once Done"; 
read -d '!' jobnames;  
echo "$jobnames" > jobs.txt       # "quotes" to preserve whitespace
```

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing out the quotes and the 'e' option. But the main problem is still there. When I paste say 40 lines it works properly but when someone else does it on the same system it will randomly cut some lines. Also, in SSH Tectia in will only take about 10 lines or so

Comment: What do you mean by "paste", I don't see a `paste` command anywhere there.  Are you using a GUI to paste into `read`?

Comment: In the original, `!` was actually *unquoted* (`echo "Press "!" once done"`), but `!` expands also within double quotes, which your single quotes within double quotes don't prevent. The safe way would be to escape it: `echo "Press \"\!\" once done"`. Newer versions of Bash don't expand the `!` if it is the last character between double quotes, but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I noticed it was unquoted originally.  Yes, you are right about escaping the quotes.  Corrected, thanks.

Comment: To be extra safe, you should escape `!` itself, as double quoting doesn't prevent history expansion, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction). `!\"` expands to the last command that started with `"`, for example.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I have to admit that when I first read this question I thought it might be an issue with `!`.  Then I was convinced it was the `read -de`.  Now I think the user is using a GUI with mouse to paste text into the terminal reply to `read`.  Then that depends on the terminal emulator and GUI in use, and nothing to do with `bash`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I understand the question any longer ;)

Comment: Yes I meant paste as in paste from say notepad into the terminal with right click or similar function.

Comment: So if this is not an issue with bash, what could be causing the shell not taking the entire paste input from Windows?

Comment: @PFD:  It could be a limit to the buffer that the GUI allows you to copy, it could be a limit on the emulator that allows you to paste, or it could be a strange character screwing the whole thing up.  Or it could be more than one of these.  Note:  its not the shell (`bash`) that is stopping you, the shell does not have a paste buffer, it is down to the Graphical User Interface you are running the shell in.

Comment: @cdarke: Someone recommended to use VI to paste large amount of text. So instead of using read the menu will open VI instead and once done it will go back to the menu. So my option 1 will look like this `1) vi jobs.txt ;;`
This seems to work but there are a few more steps you need to do to save and exit from VI which isn't as ideal as just pasting at the prompt. But I'm not sure if there is a better way to save a large amount of text from Windows paste function.

Comment: Why not read it direct from the file, rather than requiring the user to copy and paste?